# Find range of a set where values in the set wrap around a modulus

Tags: python, modulo

I have a Python set containing numbers representing hours on a 24 hour clock, for example

```
s = set([1, 3, 8, 23])
s
>>> {1, 3, 8, 23}
```

I want to find the size of the smallest range of hours that covers every hour in the set. Normally I could use

```
max(s) - min(s)
22
```

But in this case, the smallest range is allowed to wrap around the modulus (midnight), so the answer would be wrong. The correct answer would be that all the values occur between 23 and 8, so the smallest range is 9 hours.

Is there an efficient way to calculate this using Python?

Comment: To be clear, you want the minimum of max(s) - min(s) and max(s) - second_largest?

Comment: @timgeb .. Not exactly, I want the smallest range that covers all the entries in the set, regardless of whether that range crosses midnight or not..

Comment: @timgeb, Taking the sample data, the max is 23, the second largest is 8. 23 - 8 + 1 = 16. You are right though that these values are both ends of the 'minimum range'. I think that if I do : 24 - max(s) + second_max(s) this gets the right answer. I'm checking now to see if this works in all cases. Thanks for setting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sort the set and append first hour of another day (`l[0] + 24`)
- find differences
- the result is 24 - maximal difference

---

```
>>> l = sorted(s)
>>> l.append(l[0] + 24)
>>> 24 - max(b-a for a,b in zip(l, l[1:]))
9
```

Comment: Very nice! Works for all my test cases.

Comment: Agreed!  I particularly like zipping the list with itself off by one - much cleaner than my range(len(l))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.
First, take a sorte list of your set of hours:

```
s = set([1, 3, 8, 23])
sortedhours = sorted(s)
```

then, get all wrapping of those hours around midnight:

```
twodays = sortedhours + [h+24 for h in sortedhours]
allwraps = [twodays[i-len(s):i] for i in range(len(s), len(twodays))]
```

then, do what you asked to do, i.e. compute the minimal range on all the wrapping around midnight:

```
min(map(lambda l: max(l)-min(l), allwraps))
# 9
```

Comment: This works as expected - i suspect (but haven't tested) that @pacholiks answer is more efficient though.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to treat each element as a starting point, and consider what the range is with that:

```
l = sorted(s)
ans = l[-1] - l[0]
for i in range(len(l)):     # I know that's horrible normally
    wrapped = l[i-1] - l[i] + 24
    if wrapped < ans:
       ans = wrapped
```

Comment: thanks - I can see what you're trying to do. It doesn't work as it stands at the moment though, this returns 2 (it should return 9)

Comment: Bother!  Yes, I had two list elements the wrong way round.